# python creating new column with results in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with float values. I want to create a new column that is the ratio of columns A and B of my dataframe.

what am i doing wrong ?

```
df['Result']= np.nan if (np.isnan(df['A']) or np.isnan(df['B'])) else df['B']/df['A']
```

Comment: you have to provide enough code./ sample data and show us your desired output and if you are getting error message include the full trace

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way with `np.where`,

```
df['Result'] = np.where((np.isnan(df['A']) | np.isnan(df['B'])), np.nan, df['B'] / df['A'])
```

**Issue with your approach:**

The value `np.nan` is being assigned to the entire 'Result' column, ***regardless of whether the conditions specified in the if statement are met***. The if statement is not being used to control which rows in the 'Result' column get assigned a value of `np.nan` and which rows get assigned a value of `df['B']/df['A']`.

To use the if statement to control the assignment of values to the 'Result' column, you would need to use a **loop** to iterate over the rows in the DataFrame and test the conditions for each row. Like-

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if np.isnan(row['A']) or np.isnan(row['B']):
        df.loc[i, 'Result'] = np.nan
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'Result'] = row['B'] / row['A']
```

Answer (score 0):

hello you can also use np.select() : that very helpfull when you have alot of condition

```
#step1: creat list of condition 

condition= [ 
            df['A'].notnull()|df['B'].notnull(),
            df['A'].isnull()|df['B'].isnull()
            ]
#step2: creat list of values

values= [(df['B'] / df['A']),np.nan]
#then create clomun and put the value if condition is True

df['Result']=np.select(condition,values)
```